# Blocking route clicks while resolving beforeRouteLeave in a view?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

If I click a navigation button to leave the view with the code below, it works fine. The router waits until the code is resolved, and moves on to the next route view page.

```
async beforeRouteLeave(_to: object, _from: object, _next: Function) {
    await this.resolveStuff();
    _next();
}
```

However, if I keep clicking the navigation buttons (spamming the buttons), the same *beforeRouteLeave* above keeps getting fired over and over, while it still is resolving its issues from the first click. When the promise finally is resolved, the router hangs and does not enter the next page. I would like that the router waits until the *beforeRouteLeave* is finished before taking on more navigation.

I am using Vue router 4 release candidate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blocking route clicks is effectively done in the beforeEach route hook:

```
router.beforeEach(to, from, next) => { if (routerPaused) next(false); });
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe creating a flag that is set to true before "beforeRouteLeave" and set to false once it is resolved, and with that preventing the trigger of a second "beforeRouteLeave"?

**[EDIT]**

example:

```
var isLoading = false


.
.
.


async beforeRouteLeave(_to: object, _from: object, _next: Function) {
   if(isLoading){
      return false // do nothing exit function
   } else {
      isLoading = true // set to true to prevent multiple executions 
   }
   await this.resolveStuff();

   isLoading = false // All done, from now on we can invoke "beforeRouteLeave" again

    _next();
}
```

Comment: I tried this. First it complains that *The "next" callback was never called inside of "beforeRouteLeave"*. After adding *_next(false)*, the router still hangs.